# В Service при использовании mediaPlayer.prepareAsync() не стартует музыка

Tags: java, android, mediaplayer, android-service

В `Service` при использовании `mediaPlayer.prepareAsync()` не стартует музыка. Если использую `mediaPlayer.prepare()` то все ок, а с асинхронным потоком беда, как можно исправить?

```
public class PlayMusicService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;



@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

          mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://online.radiorecord.ru:8101/rr_128");
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
           if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {

        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}

public void onDestroy() {
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
    mediaPlayer.release();
}



public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer) {
    stopSelf();

}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    if (!mp.isPlaying()) {

        mp.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: если ответ решил вашу проблему, то вы можете отметить его "верным" нажав галочку слева от тела ответа, сразу под  стрелочками, позволяющими голосовать за/против ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы вызываете `mediaPlayer.start();` в `onStartCommand`, не дождавшись Prepared.

> A MediaPlayer object must first enter the Prepared state before playback can be started.

...

> It is important to note that the Preparing state is a transient state, and the behavior of calling any method with side effect while a MediaPlayer object is in the Preparing state is undefined.

Уберите этот вызов, оставьте `mp.start()` только в колбэке `onPrepared`. Кроме того, `isPlaying()` проверять в `onPrepared` смысла нет. Почитайте [документацию](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) о состояних MediaPlayer'а. Он очень ловко бросает `IllegalStateException` при неправильном порядке вызовов методов.

ЗЫ И смотрите в logcat там наверняка есть что-то о проблемах...

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало)))